# Omnoauth login using Linkedin not supply email in info hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise, omniauth, linkedin-api

I am using omniauth with LinkedIn as a provider.  LinkedIn doesn't supply 
an email in info hash, so i cannot provide an email when create the user based 
on the information I get back.

Two related questions:

1) How can I adjust devise so that there isn't a requirement 
for :email as a validation?  It doesn't appear to be set under the 
User model.

2) I do want to get the email information, however, so want to have 
email information requested before creating the User.  How can I 
redirect to a page/wizard asking for email information and then come 
back to finish the user registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the railscasts about omniauth: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth

The idea is the following:

- Create a new user from the omniauth info
- try to save the user
- since the email is not present it won't validate
- store the omniauth data in the session and `redirect_to new_user_registration_url`
- create your own registration controller that inheritates from the devise one
- override the `build_resource(*args)` method, and if the omniauth data is present, use it to create the resource (User in your case)

That way, after trying to login with linkedin, the user will be redirected to a form where he will be able to enter his email.

It's all explained in the railscast ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer but do you have any example for that where I can get reference. I could not found on rails cast video can you suggest the url for that?

Comment: I think it's in this one: http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2 . Your problem is not directly in there I think, but it handles the case where the login or email are already taken. And it's exactly the same principle as if the email was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this without needing to use the separate 'linkedin' gem, it was pretty difficult as there was a distinct lack of documentation on the subject!

Firstly you need to make the email-address available by adding the fields option to your LinkedIn Omniauth configuration, you will also need to override the request_token_path in order to add the r_emailaddress scope required to retrieve a users email address.

Mine ended up looking something like this (NB. Ruby 1.9.3):

```
provider :linkedin, external_services['linkedin']['api_key'], external_services['linkedin']['api_secret'], client_options: {request_token_path: '/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_emailaddress'}, fields: ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'headline', 'industry', 'picture-url', 'public-profile-url', 'email-address']
```

**NOTE: Dont forget to change external_services['linkedin']['api_key'] and external_services['linkedin']['api_secret'] to your own.**

Your user will then be asked to authorise use of their email address as well as their basic provide and you will have access to it once they are returned via:

```
auth['extra']['raw_info']['emailAddress']
```

I should probably commit this change back to omniauth-linkedin so you can simply set scope: r_emailaddress in the provider options, avoid the duplication of the field names and get the email back in the info section of the auth object.

If I get time after this section of my project is finished I will.